# Merging duplicate contacts on table MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to merge and delete duplicate contacts on a table.

Part 1: Since some of the duplicates have values (phone, fax, etc) where as the others don't I am using the MAX function to get all the corresponding values. There are very few that have contradictory information. This contradictory info, will be fixed manually. I have stored the data using the MAX function to a temp table and updated the contact table, so that all duplicated contacts have the same information. 
Part 2: Now I need to select 1 of the duplicated contact as a master and Update the references for the other "child" duplicate contacts to the master and then delete the child duplicate contacts.

I am attempting to start on Part 2, but I am unsure how I can select one distinct contact-id from the duplicated. Also can this be achieved easily with merge statement (part 1 and 2 combined).

```
select DISTINCT c.namefml from contact c
where c.contactrecordtype = 'CONTACT'
and c.inactive<>'T'

group by c.namefml
HAVING COUNT (c.namefml)>1

This selects the distinct duplicate contacts based on the name. Now how would I select TOP 1 from each of these: 


 Select DISTINCT contactid, namefml
    from contact c
    where namefml = (select DISTINCT c.namefml from contact c
    where c.contactrecordtype = 'CONTACT'
    and c.inactive<>'T'

    group by c.namefml
    HAVING COUNT (c.namefml)>1)
```

This does not work.

```
Select DISTINCT contactid, c.namefml
from contact c
inner join (select DISTINCT c.namefml from contact c
where c.contactrecordtype = 'CONTACT'
and c.inactive<>'T'

group by c.namefml
HAVING COUNT (c.namefml)>1) s 
on s.namefml=c.namefml
```

This does not work either, as it gets all the duplicates instead of just the top 1.

Answer (score 0):

If in your select statement you use a `row_number() OVER(Partition by namefml order by namefml) as [RowNum]`.  This would provide you with a column called RowNum that increments by one for every same namefml.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT contactid,
                    namfml,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY namefml ORDER BY contactid) AS [RowNum]
    FROM contact c
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

So this would select all the firsts of the duplicates.

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: "This selects the distinct duplicate contacts based on the name. Now how would I select TOP 1 from each of these:"   Replace everything below this line with what I provided, and tell me if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Select TOP 1 c.contactid, c.namefml
from contact c
inner join (SELECT DISTINCT contactid,
                    namefml,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY namefml ORDER BY contactid) AS [RowNum]
    FROM contact c where c.contactrecordtype='CONTACT' and c.inactive<>'T') s 
on s.namefml=c.namefml
where s.RowNum=1

Comment: It only displays the Top 1.

Comment: No this does not work. Its giving me double the duplicates. 1069 contacts when it should only return 183. Thanks though.